# Passing return value as function arguments (tuple)

Tags: javascript, function, tuples, return, arguments

I'm trying to use the return value of my function as arguments for my function, however the fact that it's a tuple is being problematic. This is further compounded by the fact that it will not always be a tuple.

```
function foo(initial_state, indexer = 0) {
// does something

return [initial_state, indexer + 1];
}
```

I want to be able to sometimes use the function as simply

```
foo(initial_state);
```

but also I want to call the function with the return, as such..

```
foo(foo());
```

Instead of the desired behavior, the tuple is put into initial_state, whereas I  would want it deconstructed to match the arguments in the function.

I can obviously do a temporary variable like

```
let some_state, some_index = foo();
foo(some_state, some_index);
```

But that seems very ugly. There has to be a better way.

Comment: *'I can obviously do a temporary variable like'* the example is incorrect, perhaps you meant using destructuring? `let [some_state, some_index] = foo();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the spread syntax:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

```js
function foo(initial_state, indexer = 0) {
  return [initial_state, indexer + 1];
}

console.log(foo(...foo(0, 0)));
```

Comment: @pilchard oops, actually i wrote it as a spread operator first, but you are right, its spread syntax... good to learn

Comment: @pilchard the name 'rest parameters' is misleading though, parameters is what you pass into a function, arguments is what you get inside the function from parameters. should be called rest arguments imho

Answer (score 1):

You can't create temporary variables like that actually.

```
let some_state, some_index = foo();
```

That way, only `some_index` will be assigned to `foo()`'s return value. `some_state` will  be undefined.

You could do so using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#array_destructuring) though

```
let [some_state, some_index] = foo();
```

But you can just spread the array to another function.

```js
foo(...foo(state, indexer))
```